# Hide columns based on content (sum of rows)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I'm trying to hide columns based on the sum of selected rows (i.e., cells) in those columns.

For example - if the sum of E9:E12 is 0, then hide column E.

Additionally, and probably a little harder - if a column is not going to be hidden, ensure the next column does not hide, even if the sum of its corresponding rows is zero.

For example - if the sum of E9:E12 is not 0, then do not hide E, and do not hide column F, even if the sum of F9:F12 is zero.

Comment: Hi Ian, it would be helpful if you could give us some insight into your data and why you need to do this. It would also help to know what you've done so far.

Comment: Your row and column references don't match-rows are denoted by numbers and columns by letters.  Yet your example references Row E. Please clarify so we can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will, obviously, take some VBA to pull off. I see a potential problem with your logic, but the VBA will do exactly as you requested. I'll talk about the problem at the end.

Open your VBE with Ctrl+F11 and create a new Module for your workbook. In that module add:

```
Sub hideColumns()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("YOUR SHEET NAME") '<--CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SHEET

    Dim col As Range
    Dim row, sum As Integer

    'loop through every column in the worksheet
    For Each col In ws.Columns

        'Resetting the sum for this column
        sum = 0

        'Loop through rows 9 to 12 to get their sum
        For row = 9 To 12 '<--Rows that you want to sum in each column
            sum = sum + ws.Cells(row, col.Column).Value
        Next row

        'Only hide the column if the sum is 0 and previous column is not hidden
        '    OR if the sum is 0 and this is the first column (there would be no previous column)        
        col.Hidden = ((sum = 0) And Not Cells(1, col.Column - 1).Hidden) Or ((sum = 0) And col.Column = 1)

    Next col
End Sub
```

Now the problem: We loop through every column, and lets say that we don't encounter a sum of 0 until Column 3... then because Column 2 is visible, then by your logic, we don't hide column 3.. repeat until you get to the end of the sheet. Essentially the logic you outlines will close up columns until it encounters a column with a sum of 0. If that column with a sum of 0 is Column 1, then... nothing gets hidden. If this isn't your desired behavior, then let me know and I can rewrite to get you there.